# Discord.js searching for specific channel name to send a message to(logs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

im tryna make it so when the mute command is used it sends the feedback to the logs channel if theres a logs channel heres my code

```
let logs = Client.channels.find(ch => ch.name = 'logs')

logs.send(embed)
```

it works but instead of sending to my #logs it sends to my #video-suggestions (i ran the command in #bot-setup)

[visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJtvA.png)

any help is apreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
var logs = Client.channels.find(ch => ch.name === "logs");
```

instead of:

```
var logs = Client.channels.find(ch => ch.name = "logs");
```

To compare two values, use `==` or `===` and use `=` to assign a value to a variable.